# How to copy directory in Gradle preserving symlinks?

Tags: gradle, build, symlink

The following gradle task copies directory but resolves all symlinks. This is unacceptable. I want to preserve.

```
task test {
    doLast {
        copy {
            from 'source'
            to 'destination'
        }
    }
}
```

What can be done about it?

Comment: this is a known limitation from Gradle, see:  https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/3982

Answer (score 5):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/3982) for that "bug"

For now you can detect the symlinks and maybe create it manually

```
import java.nio.file.FileSystems
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Path

copy {
    from $source
    into $destination
    eachFile { details ->
        Path pathFile = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(details.file.path)
        if(Files.isSymbolicLink(pathFile)) {
            details.exclude()
            commandLine 'ln', '-s', Files.readSymbolicLink(pathFile), "$destination/${details.relativePath}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This example doesn't work with `gradle` 8.2. I get `commandLine` not found.  At the link to the open issue, there is a better example that extends the Copy task.